# mod_proxy apache httpd 2.2.* . (rhel6) reverse_proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, rhel6

I'm trying to migrate a website from on premise to AWS cloud. I want to keep the current site live and test the AWS hosted version as well.

The apps pseudo hostname is www.hostname.com to have a proxy with a hostname of www.b.hostname.com that takes the request and (transforms it) before going to www.hostname.com(in AWS) as if the request originally to www.hostname.com instead of www.a.hostname.com. Maybe I'm over thinking this, but I believe this can be accomplished with mod_proxy (reverse proxy?). I will generate a ssl certificate for www.a.hostname.com since the traffic must be over 443.

Could someone help guide me the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: What's wrong with using `/etc/hosts`? How complicated does your testing need to be?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look into using `mod_rewrite` to update `www.b.hostname.com` to `www.hostname.com`

Reference: `https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/proxy.html`